# Do @replies notify poster of another answer

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

From what I can find, @replies only notify other users when used in comments. Does this also work across different answers?

What I mean is when writing an answer that expands on a previous answer (e.g. https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/12240), users will often @reply the author of the previous answer. Will that author get a notification, or is it simply a spillover of the way people are used to using it in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this does *not* work across answers. Only commenters *on the specific post* (answer or question) can be notified.

Quoting from [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> - Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties, commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and editors **of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified**.

Emphasis mine.